# CakePhp and subdomain routing

Tags: cakephp, routes, subdomain

I'm trying to make subdomains working on my website, however, I still not able to generate links to subdomains...

I used the code I found in the net:

```
<?php

class SubdomainRoute extends CakeRoute {

    public function match ($params) {
        $subdomain = isset($params['subdomain']) ? $params['subdomain'] : null;
        unset($params['subdomain']);
        $path = parent::match($params);
        if ($subdomain) {
            $path = 'http://' . $subdomain . '.localhost' . $path;
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work for me. Anyone tried to find a solution and got one please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never I guess, but in order to use the above code you have to go to `app/Config/routes.php` and use the class:

```
App::uses('SubdomainRoute', 'Routing/Route');
```

As well as add it to your route:

```
Router::connect( '/:controller/:action/*', 
    [ 'controller' => 'test' ],
    [ 'routeClass' => 'SubdomainRoute' ]
);
```

Hope this helps... someone :)